# SSL: Certbot + AWS Lightsail + LetsEncrypt + Really Simple SSL Plugin

Tags: wordpress, apache, ssl, debian, amazon-lightsail

Scenario:
Current server @ example.com is running an older version of amazon AWS Lightsail with wordpress (ubuntu) and we just had a new certificate issued using letsencrypt. All is well. Original cert was requested with wildcard, so functional for any subdomain.

Now, we needed to spin up a fresh new server for a subdomain, let's call it development.example.com.

The new AWS lightsail instances now are no longer Ubuntu but Debian!

The idea was to install certbot in the new Debian instance and then copy over the certificate files from the primary server @ example.com.

I've done this successfully in the past when it was going from Ubuntu to Ubuntu but now that the new instance is Debian, the Really Simple SSL plugin does not recognize that a certificate is installed.

STEPS I took to move the certificate files:
What I've done before is simply to copy /etc/letsencrypt/* from one server to another and then follow the steps outlined in the AWS documentation here:
https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/amazon-lightsail-using-lets-encrypt-certificates-with-wordpress#complete-the-prerequisites-lets-encrypt-wordpress

In this case, performing the steps 7.4, 7.5, 7.6 and section 8.

However, steps described in section 8.1 do not appear valid in this document anymore for Debian, because there is no such location on Debian:
sudo chmod 666 /opt/**bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs**/wp-config.php

AND because it seems an .htaccess does not exist either.
sudo chmod 666 /opt/**bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/htaccess.conf**

Are there additional steps now which I've missed to be able to copy the necessary files for SSL to work properly on this new subdomain server now running Debian?

I was going to go through a new certificate request in the development server but wouldn't that invalidate the certificate currently installed for the primary domain?

In other words, how to properly copy the SSL files from the main Ubuntu server and configure the Debian subdomain server so that both wordpress installations have SSL correctly installed?

Comment: Thanks @MikeMoy so that will not invalidate the certificate currently already installed in the main domain example.com?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @mikemoy indeed, one can issue multiple wildcard certificates from different servers in a subdomain. Just went ahead and issued a new certificate.